# Solr 4 Host Port and Context information (ZooKeeper Base URL) settings

Tags: solr, solrj, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to upgrade from Solr 4-Beta to Solr 4.  While using Solr 4-beta, I configured the host and port number in Solr.xml file as below, and everything worked fine.

```
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores host="xxx.xx.x.xxx" adminPath="/admin/cores" hostPort="8180" hostContext="solr4" sharedLib="lib">
  </cores>
</solr>
```

But when I upgraded to Solr 4.0, the ZooKeeper base URL is being set to "http://Computer-name:8983/Solr" which throws the below exception while contacting the other nodes.  For some reason the ZooKeeper initialization is not picking the host and port information from the Solr.xml, but is getting the default Solr port and context information.   Can someone please help on how to correct this ZooKeeper's base_url?

```
SEVERE: Error while trying to recover. core=collection1:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://ComputerName:8983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.sendPrepRecoveryCmd(RecoveryStrategy.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:220)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: COMPUTER-NAME
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1202)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:352)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solr.xml config looks okay. Except `sharedLib="lib"`, sharedLib attribute belongs to tag `<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">`.

Exception `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: COMPUTER-NAME`

Please ensure following:

1) ZooKeeper hostname(s) provided in `zkHost` param are mapped in `hosts` file

```
-DzkHost=COMPUTER-NAME:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183
```

Hosts file definition

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     COMPUTER-NAME
```

2) Updated `solr.xml` present in correct path of `SOLR_HOME`

Comment: Thanks.  The point #2 helped.  Actually it is a silly mistake, which cost us lot of time.  In the new version of the jar, the SOLR_HOME was not set correctly, so it could not pick up the host and port names correctly.